# Duplicate results with excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet (COLLABT) on an excel file that displays some informations from 3 other worksheets (COLLAB1,COLLAB2 and COLLAB3). My problem is that i have duplicates of the results.
Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Here is the code of my macro

```
    Sub COLLABT()
With Sheets("COLLABT")
.Range("A2:O65536").Delete
      For Each sh In Sheets
Select Case sh.Name
  Case "COLLAB1", "COLLAB2", "COLLAB3"
    For lg = 2 To sh.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
      LgS = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
      .Cells(LgS, 1) = sh.Cells(lg, 1)
      .Cells(LgS, 2) = sh.Cells(lg, 2)
      .Cells(LgS, 3) = sh.Cells(lg, 3)
      .Cells(LgS, 4) = sh.Cells(lg, 4)
      .Cells(LgS, 5) = sh.Cells(lg, 5)
      .Cells(LgS, 6) = sh.Cells(lg, 6)
      .Cells(LgS, 7) = sh.Cells(lg, 7)
      .Cells(LgS, 8) = sh.Cells(lg, 8)
      .Cells(LgS, 9) = sh.Cells(lg, 9)
      .Cells(LgS, 10) = sh.Cells(lg, 10)
      .Cells(LgS, 11) = sh.Cells(lg, 11)
      .Cells(LgS, 12) = sh.Cells(lg, 12)
      .Cells(LgS, 13) = sh.Cells(lg, 13)
      .Cells(LgS, 14) = sh.Cells(lg, 14)
      .Cells(LgS, 15) = sh.Cells(lg, 15)

    Next


End Select
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the current result

[image]

Here is what it should be

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX2Wo.png)

Comment: A lot will depend on what you mean by "duplicates", but have you tried using Excel's "Remove Duplicates" feature?  (Either manually or via code.)

Comment: Are the duplicates due to the code, or do your various COLLAB sheets have duplicates when all combined on the main sheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne I think it's the code. Have a look at the screenshots i posted. It seems to have nothing to do with my sheets duplicates.

Comment: @YowE3K No I didn't. Please have a look at the screenshots.

Comment: Without seeing what is on sheets "COLLAB1", "COLLAB2" and "COLLAB3", it's hard to tell whether the problem is with the code or with the data.

Comment: @YowE3K  Just random things for testing purposes. I'll upload screenshots of both sheets in a few seconds.

Comment: @YowE3K. Can't add them to the main post. Here they are.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3qiR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Q4L.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZiav.png

Comment: Yeah, you have duplicate data, don't you? Just run `Remove Duplicates` after it's all on your main sheet...Unless I'm missing something.  How do you know which ones to keep, is it based on column A?  That does change...but perhaps *before* adding to the sheet, do a check that If value X already exists in main sheet, go to next row, otherwise copy?

Comment: @BruceWayne - But that final results is showing **two** of everything.  I.e. 8 rows from COLLAB1, 7 rows from COLLAB2, 7 rows from COLLAB3 = 22 rows, but COLLABT has those 22 rows **twice**.

Comment: Your code shows no check to see if a record exists before dumping the row data into the master sheet. If you do not want to check to see if a record exists then use remove duplicates (as suggested by @BruceWayne) after dumping all of the records.

Comment: @MaximusE. I tested the code and it works for me (providing I first put something into row 1 of COLLABT so that the `UsedRange.Rows.Count` gives the correct last row - but without that fix it just writes everything to row 2 over and over)

Comment: @BruceWayne You're right, it works. I was expecting a different behavior. How can i automate the process like you suggested ?

Comment: Record yourself doing it.

Comment: @YowE3K That's exactly what i was talking about. i have the final results twice. I put the same things in row 1 of COLLABT as i have in COLLAB1 to 3,  but i still have twice the result. Did i miss something?

Comment: I'd still like to know **why** it is generating two of every record!!  (Remove Duplicates will fix the symptoms, but I'd rather find the cause of the problem.)

Comment: @Jeeped what should i add to my code to check if a record exists?

Comment: @MaximusE. - If you put the same things in row 1 of COLLABT as each of the other sheets, why don't they still appear in your screendump - that may be another symptom of what is happening.

Comment: @YowE3K I manually deleted everything from the COLLABT sheet to see if it would fix the issue while i was looking for a solution (just CTRL+A and DEL). I forgot to copy back the first row afterwards.

Comment: @MaximusE. If you did a CTRL+A / DEL, you would have ended up with information only in row 2.  Do you have other code that you haven't included in the question?

Comment: @YowE3K I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out. Granted, I am not very good at coding, but still.

Comment: @YowE3K I have 2 pivot tables in the "synthese collaborateur" and "detail collaborateur" sheets.
The only coded besides the macro is the click button 

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
COLLABT
End Sub

Did the same thing once again. CTRL+A / DEL. it deleted the first row (titles), and still gave me twice the result, like shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @MaximusE. I'm going to have to give up and start working on my paid job now, but I will certainly be coming back later today to see if anyone has come up with an explanation for this!

Comment: @YowE3K No problem. Thanks a lot for you help, much appreciated.
AS a side note, i kept pressing the button after that CTRL+A/ DEL and it skipped a few rows before duplicating the results...

Comment: @Jeeped I recorded the macro, then tried to copy the resulting code at the end of my 1st macro, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things in this code which I instinctively don't like. Such as,

1. It calls a lot of sheet it doesn't want to use.
2. It uses `.End(xlUp).Row` as the last number in the `For ... Next` declaration. I distrust this number if it is calculated anew on each loop in which I make changes to worksheets.
3. The code also used `.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1` to introduce instability. I like to take control of my numbers before the looping starts and then keep control of them while looping.

The following code does that.

```
Sub COLLABT()

    Dim ShNames() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rsl As Long                             ' Last row: Source
    Dim Rs As Long, Rt                          ' Row: Source / Target

    ShNames = Split("COLLAB1,COLLAB2,COLLAB3", ",")
    With Worksheets("COLLABT")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count))
        Rng.ClearContents

        For i = 0 To UBound(ShNames)
            Set Sh = Worksheets(ShNames(i))
            Rt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Rsl = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For Rs = 2 To Rsl
                Set Rng = Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(Rs, 1), Sh.Cells(Rs, 15))
                Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rt, 1)
                Rt = Rt + 1
            Next Rs
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I don't say that any of the above mentioned factors must be to blame, but they might, and if my code doesn't produce the same result that would prove my point.

Frankly, when asked what the real source of the problem might be, I would look at the calling of the procedure first. Is there an event procedure somewhere in the background that reacts to anything the code does and effectively calls it twice? Or, even simpler, is this an error which can only occur during testing, such as the data actually being duplicated in one of the source sheets? That's what I would check first, but since I don't have access to the facts, I wrote code. Please try it.

Comment: Fixed the duplicates, thanks. But it doesn't copy some of the fields to COLLABT as it should: the date column (B) returns #######, the I column is not returned for COLLAB2 and 3. Samethings goes for parts of the E column.

Comment: I'm glad the duplicates issue was fixed. So, your question was answered, your problem solved, and what remains is for you to accept the answer. If the code doesn't copy the parts you want, that is another matter which should be posted as another question and will receive an answer, from me or others, if it complies with site rules which, at this moment, it doesn't.

Comment: When you start your own effort prior to asking your next question please bear in mind that `######` is an output Excel uses to indicate overflow, meaning the column is too narrow to display the cell's assigned value. You often get this with dates. The cure is to either widen the column or change the date format. In the context of this thread I see it as an indication that my code assigns a value to a wrong column. Expanding the column to see what causes the error may help you find its source, eliminating the need for another question.

Comment: Thank you. Found it yesterday.